# How to remove picture URL from twitter tweet using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe from twitterscraper and I am trying to remove the **picture URL** from the text

**Input** : Hello everyone, have a good day. pic.twitter.com/Z1yG39NO

**Output** : Hello everyone, have a good day.

```
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: re.split('https:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', str(x))[0])
```

I use this code but it can remove only https:

Thank you :-)

Comment: `df['text'].str.split('pic').str[0]`?

Comment: `df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(r'\S*twitter.com\S*', '')` ..?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
def cleaning_PicURL (text):
    text = re.sub(r'pic.twitter.com/[\w]*',"", text)
    return text

df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: cleaning_PicURL(x))
```

Use the above code it will remove the picture URL from the text, here `split` function will split the text to the matching regex pattern and give us a list. In tweets you may not be sure where will be the position of your picture URL, so it is more relevant to use `sub` function instead of `split` function, as `sub` function will directly removes the matching text with empty string, it does the job easy for you. The regex pattern `pic.twitter.com/[\w]*` will help in matching all the twitter picture URL's in your text. hope this clears your doubt.

Example:

```
re.sub(r'pic.twitter.com/[\w]*',"", "test pic.twitter.com/va4nFjFQ5B")
'test '
```

Comment: please be a bit clearer with your writing. Our objective is also to teach those who have asked =)

Comment: Added more explanation for the provided codes, it will be more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

### Do this :

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(r'pic.twitter.com(.*?)\s(.*)', '')
```

`(.*?)\s(.*)`  put this for the rest of the url that is specific for each post